# NSXMLParser foundCDATA for specific element

Tags: iphone, nsxmlparser

I have this XML file:

```
<item>
<title>App1</title>
<link><![CDATA[SomeLink]]></link>
<description><![CDATA[SomeText]]></description>
</item>
```

How can I get CDATA for each element and save it to each NSMutableDictionary?
There is no elementName to compare in foundCDATA delegate.

I tried this line in foundCharacters:

```
if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"link"]) [currentLink appendString:string];
```

But I get nil, and I cannot remove foundCDATA delegate because I'm using it for another parser in the same viewcontroller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There is no elementName to compare in foundCDATA delegate.

Your parser delegate will have previously received `-parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:` with the element. It should use that to update its state so that it *knows* what element is being parsed when the next message comes in. That's true whether the message is `-foundCDATA:` or `-foundCharacters:` or something else.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an instance variable (e.g. NSString *currentElement) to the delegate class, then set the value of that variable by adding this code to the delegate:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
    currentElement = elementName;
}
```

Then you'll have access to the name of the current element in foundCDATA.

Answer (score 0):

The best (more precisely the most general) approach is to somehow build a stack from the nesting elements; this, in effect, will give you the ability to see the entire structure from top to bottom of your XML document during parsing. See how I do this while building an RSS parser: https://github.com/H2CO3/RSSKit/blob/master/RSSParser.m

Basically, what you have to do is implement `parser:didStartElement:` etc. and `parser:didEndElement:` (I don't type the full selector names for the sake of simplicity). Then maintain either a string of Unix-like file paths (that's what I'm doing) adding a component in the former method and deleting it in the latter one, or you can build an NSMutableArray or even a custom stack object for pushing the necessary parameters of the XML element.